# How can I set the date field in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I wrote following scr but my form field is still empty.

```
     function callme(e) {
        let today = new Date();
            document.getElementById('dtCikisTarih').value = today;                  
    }
```

My form field has a specific definition as

```
      <asp:Button ID="btnAktar" runat="server" Text="Aktar" CommandName="AktarRow"  class = "inp" OnClientClick="return callme(this)"  />

              <iskurDateTimeBoxes:IskurDateBox ID="dtGirisTarih" runat="server" clientidmode="static"/>
              <iskurDateTimeBoxes:IskurDateBox ID="dtCikisTarih" runat="server" clientidmode="static"/>
```

Comment: What is the actual HTML rendered by IskurDateBox? If you evaluate `document.getElementById('dtCikisTarih')` in the Developer Tools console, what does it return?

Comment: Hi Michael it's as follows:   <span id="dtCikisTarih"><nobr><input name="ctl03$ucOzgecmisTecrube$dtCikisTarih$textBox" type="text" id="textBox" class="TXT" style="width:88px;"><img id="image" align="absmiddle" onclick="if (!document.getElementById(&quot;textBox&quot;).disabled){if (calendar_dtCikisTarih == null) { initialize_calendar_dtCikisTarih(); } showCalendar(document.getElementById(&quot;image&quot;), calendar_dtCikisTarih, document.getElementById(&quot;textBox&quot;));}" src="/WebResource.axd?d=l_FvwzHSe5INOKQeN-AXcD0Jeo12oHRcoM2rIUcYXq4hKAwds1w2&amp;t=638282893944488518"></nobr></span>

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information. But I can see that `dtCikisTarih` is the wrong ID; it refers not to the `<input>` but to the `<span>`, which doesn't have a `value`.

Comment: Michael you are right when I set right id it worked.

Answer (score 0):

to set the date field in javascript
your code should be like this

```
    let today = new Date();
    
    // Format the date as needed (YYYY-MM-DD)
    let formattedDate = today.toISOString().substr(0, 10);

    // Set the value of the input field
    document.getElementById('dtCikisTarih').value = formattedDate;
```

issue with setting the date value directly as a Date object. You need to format the date as a string in the appropriate format that the input field expects

Answer (score 0):

This code solved the problem:

```
       function callme(e) {

            var tds = e.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td');

            document.getElementById('txtFirmaAdi').value = tds[2].innerHTML.trim();              
            var txtBxs = document.getElementsByClassName('TXT');
                
            txtBxs[8].value = tds[6].innerHTML.trim().replace('&nbsp;','');
            txtBxs[9].value = tds[7].innerHTML.trim().replace('&nbsp;', '');           
        }
```

Comment: Please explain why your code solves the problem. A high quality answer helps the community way better, especially if it is also beginner-friendly. So please explain your answer in the future so everyone can understand it.